# HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field using Spring for Android

Tags: android, spring, jackson

I'm developing and Android application which communicates with my Server.

This communication is done thru Spring framework and Jackson.

I'm sending an request for my server succesfully but I'm not getting the response.

Here's what I have done:

Android app:

```
public Loja getLoja() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(
                 new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    String url = BASE_URL + "/android/played.json";
    return restTemplate.getForObject(url, Loja.class);
}
```

`Loja.class` I have two versions of it (Android and other in Server. They are completely the same:

```
public class Loja {

    private String nome;
    private String xValue;
    private String yValue;
    private String andar;
    
    public Loja(String nome, String xValue, String yValue, String andar) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.xValue = xValue;
        this.yValue = yValue;
        this.andar = andar;
    }
    
    public Loja() {
    }

    public String getAndar() {
        return andar;
    }

    public void setAndar(String andar) {
        this.andar = andar;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getxValue() {
        return xValue;
    }

    public void setxValue(String xValue) {
        this.xValue = xValue;
    }

    public String getyValue() {
        return yValue;
    }

    public void setyValue(String yValue) {
        this.yValue = yValue;
    }

}
```

And here's my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/android/played")
public ModelAndView getLoja() {
    System.out.println("Android Resquest.");
    Loja loja = new Loja("teste", "20", "30", "1");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("Loja", loja);
    return mav;
}
```

With all of this I'm getting the followin exception in Android app:

> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342): Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "Loja" (Class com.example.androidspring.Loja), not marked as ignorable
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):  at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@422e3c58; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.example.androidspring.Loja["Loja"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Loja" (Class com.example.androidspring.Loja), not marked as ignorable
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):  at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@422e3c58; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.example.androidspring.Loja["Loja"])
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:125)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:147)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:76)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:484)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at com.example.androidspring.MainActivity.getLoja(MainActivity.java:59)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at com.example.androidspring.MainActivity$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at com.example.androidspring.MainActivity$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    ... 5 more
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342): Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Loja" (Class com.example.androidspring.Loja), not marked as ignorable
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):  at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@422e3c58; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.example.androidspring.Loja["Loja"])
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:649)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:635)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1355)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:717)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2723)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1914)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:122)
> 03-21 22:13:06.197: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    ... 15 more

By what I undestood, it is not recognizing my Loja class.

But they are exactly the same! What else could it be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exception seems to suggest that while the Jackson mapper is trying to create a `Loja` from the returned json, it encountered a json field with a key of Loja, which it didn't know how to handle (because there are no fields in the `Loja` java object named "Loja"), so it failed.  This seems logical, because it appears that the server is effectively returning this json structure:

```
{"Loja":{"nome":"teste","xValue":"20","yValue":"30","andar":"1"}}
```

Because of this, you have two primary options.

1. Change the object that is passed to `getForObject()` or
2. Change the json returned from the server.

For the first one, you can have your client do a `getForObject()` passing in an `Object` that contains a `Loja`.

Something like this class:

```
class MyObj {
    private Loja Loja;

    public void setLoja(Loja loja) {
        this.Loja = loja;
    }

    public Loja getLoja() {
        return this.Loja;
    }
}
```

being used with this call:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyObj.class);
```

Alternatively, you could have your server return the `Loja` objects fields as a part of the model, or better yet, return the instance of the `Loja` object that you created.  Spring is smart enough to utilize Jackson to turn your POJO's into the proper json model you are expecting.

```
@RequestMapping("/android/played")
public Loja getLoja() {
    System.out.println("Android Resquest.");

    return new Loja("teste", "20", "30", "1");
}
```

Which would produce this json:

```
{"nome":"teste","xValue":"20","yValue":"30","andar":"1"}
```

Which would be readable by your `getForObject()` method on the client side just the way it is currently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work.. You were right about the json produced, I don't know why, but it is creating an field "Loja" at the beggining of the string. I tried to change my getLoja() return to Loja as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same json.. with your suggestion the json produced is: {"loja":{"nome":"teste","xValue":"20","yValue":"30","andar":"1"}}

Comment: Which changes did you make?  I believe I offered a couple potential solutions, not a single solution.  Could you update your question with the changes that you made that don't work?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas! It helped to figure out how to solve it! I posted an answer explaining how I did it. Check it out

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered what was wrong with my code. Nicholas was right, my JSON was something like:

```
{"Loja":{"nome":"teste","xValue":"20","yValue":"30","andar":"1"}}
```

and the field Loja wasn't being recognized when sent to Android application.

Here's what I did: I created another class called Lojas which has nothing more than a Loja List.

```
public class Lojas {

    private List<Loja> lojas;

    public Lojas() {
    }

    public List<Loja> getLojas() {
        return lojas;
    }

    public void setLojas(List<Loja> lojas) {
        this.lojas = lojas;
    }
}
```

in my getLoja() method, I'm returning this brand new method created:

```
public Lojas getLoja() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

        String url = BASE_URL + "/android/played.json";
        return restTemplate.getForObject(url, Lojas.class);
    }
```

this way, I can request an List of Loja object at once. but to do it I had to change server side to always return an List of Loja object:

```
@RequestMapping("/android/played")
    public ModelAndView getLoja() {
        System.out.println("Android Request.");

        List<Loja> list = new ArrayList<Loja>();
        list.add(new Loja("teste", "20", "30", "1"));
        list.add(new Loja("teste2", "20", "30", "1"));
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("lojas", list);
        return mav;
    }
```

Comment: You really should have accepted @nicholas.hauschild's answer and then also answered it if you wanted to add more details for others.  He did the work and his answer lead you to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem making a `JSON Post` using `RestTemplate`.

```
HTTP_HEADERS.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

final ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
final String body = ow.writeValueAsString(convertedFireCsvBeans);
final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, HTTP_HEADERS);   
final ParameterizedTypeReference<String> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>(){};
final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = REST_TEMPLATE.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, responseType);
if(responseEntity.getStatusCode() != null){
            System.out.println("HTTP STATUS CODE: " + responseEntity.getStatusCode() +
                       "\n"+ responseEntity.getStatusCode().getReasonPhrase());
                    httpStatus = responseEntity.getStatusCode();                    
                }
```

The main thing is that my `HttpEntity` I had to set to `String`.

I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

explicitly defining an empty constructor helped in my case , else my test using restTemplate would fail.

Answer (score 0):

introducing no args constructor in parent object will work.

Comment: Instead of providing the descriptive answer, try to answer with a code snippet for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

This was because, i was working on a different project, at that time, i copied a .jar file to tomcat>lib folder, if we want to succeed the new project deployment, then we need to delete that previously copied jar, because it is not relevent to the new.

Thought that anyone will be in this situation as i had.